# HDMI turning on and off on Dell Inspiron 3584 [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: gnome, dell, hdmi

I'm having some problems while using my TV and Notebook Dell Inspiron 3584 together using the Join Display's Mode. After some time the TV image goes off, and after a few minutes comes back. I did some `tail -f /var/log` to see what appears in the log when it happens and I saw these messages:

**When TV image goes off**:

```
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 29164
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.30  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz eP)
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   61.04  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (39.2 kHz e)
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 29164
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.30  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz eP)
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   61.04  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (39.2 kHz e)
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Successfully made thread 7231 of process 1873 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 1366x768 stride
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Successfully made thread 7232 of process 1873 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:26:38 Inspiron-3584 gsd-media-keys[2279]: Unable to get default sink
Jun  5 09:26:39 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 29164
Jun  5 09:26:39 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  5 09:26:39 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.30  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz eP)
Jun  5 09:26:39 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   61.04  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (39.2 kHz e)
```

**When the image comes back on:**

```
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 29164
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.30  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz eP)
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   61.04  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (39.2 kHz e)
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 3286x1080 stride
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Successfully made thread 7396 of process 1873 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Successfully made thread 7397 of process 1873 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun  5 09:31:06 Inspiron-3584 rtkit-daemon[968]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 gsd-media-keys[2279]: Unable to get default sink
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 29164
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   76.30  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz eP)
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   61.04  1366 1374 1384 1558  768 771 772 816 +hsync -vsync (39.2 kHz e)
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1947]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
Jun  5 09:31:07 Inspiron-3584 colord[1490]: failed to get session [pid 2271]: No data available
```

1. OS: Ubuntu 20.04.
2. Notebook: Dell Inspiron 3584
3. TV: Philips 39pfl4707g/78
4. HDMI Cable: Working on PS4 and Windows.

Ty.

Comment: It's probably related with a resolution the TV doesn't like.

Comment: @ChanganAuto And how do I find one acceptable?

Comment: Preferably use the TV's native resolution.